# How do I derive principal components taking account of repeated measures?

Tags: repeated-measures, pca, scales

I have data from a 24-item (each item ordinal) scale used at two time points in 2 groups - before and after treatment with treatment A and treatment B. I want to capture a core group of symptoms that are related and might respond to one treatment but not another, i.e. I want to see if the magnitude of the change in each latent variable score for each individual relates to the treatment they get.

My current method is to derive the PCs using baseline data across the whole group and then examine the end of treatment PC scores as the predicted variables in a linear mixed effects model using baseline PC score as a covariate, with group , time and group*time.

I know some of you may have immense experience in the area. Excuse the  naive exposition of the problem.

Comment: (1) When you speak of PCs, am I right in assuming it is related to classical PCA and not factor analytic methods? (2) Also, it seems the 24-item questionnaire has to do with symptoms experience or severity (with Likert-type responses categories), right? (and (3) this is not a cross-over design, but two-parallel groups?)

Comment: Sorry - away due to illness - yes you are correct in your assumptions. Thanks for any help.